# XSLT copy over the node structure of parent within foreach

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have an input XML which needs to be transformed to output format given below.
The problem i am facing is copying the exact tag "IssuedList" to the output.As I have a for each loop its not allowing to apply identical transform.Is there any other method to achieve the same result.Given below is my XSLT which i tried out

Input XML:

```
     <Books>
    <Book>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <Categories RefId="1">
      <Priority>High</Priority>
    </Category>
    </Categories>
    <Categories RefId="2">
     <Category>
      <Priority>Low</Priority>
     <Category>
    </Categories>
    <IssuedList>
    <IssueList>
     <Number>1</Number>
     <Name>ABC</Name>
     </IssueList>
     <IssueList>
     <Number>1</Number>
     <Name>ABC</Name>
     </IssueList>
    </IssuedList>
    </Book>
    <Book>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>DEF</Name>
    <Categories RefId="1">
     <Category>
      <Priority>High</Priority>
    </Category>
   </Categories>
    <Categories RefId="2">
    <Category>
      <Priority>Low</Priority>
    </Category>
    </Categories>
    <IssuedList>
    <IssueList>
     <Number>1</Number>
     <Name>DEF</Name>
     </IssueList>
    </IssuedList>
    </Book>
```

And would like to see the transformed output as

```
 <Books>
    <Book>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <RefId>1</RefId>
    <Priority>High</Priority>
    <IssuedList>
     <IssueList>
     <Number>1</Number>
     <Name>ABC</Name>
     </IssueList>
     <IssueList>
     <Number>1</Number>
     <Name>ABC</Name>
     </IssueList>
    </IssuedList>
    </Book>
    <Book>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <RefId>2</RefId>
    <Priority>Low</Priority>
    <IssuedList>
     <IssueList>
     <Number>1</Number>
     <Name>ABC</Name>
     </IssueList>
     <IssueList>
     <Number>1</Number>
     <Name>ABC</Name>
     </IssueList>
    </IssuedList>
    </Book>
    <Book>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>DEF</Name>
    <RefId>1</RefId>
    <Priority>High</Priority>
    <IssuedList>
    <IssueList>
     <Number>1</Number>
     <Name>DEF</Name>
     </IssueList>
    </IssuedList>
    </Book>
    <Book>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>DEF</Name>
    <RefId>2</RefId>
    <Priority>Low</Priority>
    <IssuedList>
    <IssueList>
     <Number>1</Number>
     <Name>DEF</Name>
     </IssueList>
    </IssuedList>
    </Book>
    </Books>
```

I have written the XSLT as below

```
<xsl:for-each select ="/Books/Book">
   <xsl:variable name="Id" select ="Id"></xsl:variable>
   <xsl:variable name="Name" select ="Name"></xsl:variable>
   <xsl:for-each select ="Categories/Category">
            <Book>                          
                <RefId>
                  <xsl:value-of select ="@RefId"></xsl:value-of>
                </RefId>
                 <Id>
                  <xsl:value-of select ="$Id"></xsl:value-of>
                </Id>
                <Name>
                  <xsl:value-of select ="$Name"></xsl:value-of>
                </Name>
 </Book>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are making this much more complicated than it needs to be. Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Books>
        <xsl:for-each select ="Books/Book/Category">
            <Book>
                <xsl:copy-of select ="../Id"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select ="../Name"/>
                <RefId><xsl:value-of select ="@RefId"/></RefId>
                <xsl:copy-of select ="Priority"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select ="../IssuedList"/>
            </Book>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Books>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: michael...I was putting a dummy data and realized that actually one level of hierarchy was missed category is within categories.So .. refers to a parent node...So additional Categories comes between book and category and i want issuedlist which is within book and not categories..

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input Michael..Traced one level up using ../../It works now and is very simplified